# While creating policy got erro function' object has no attribute 'put_bucket_policy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a bucket which is public

Below is the code

```
import json
import boto3

bucket_name = 'some-backet-name'
def s3_client():

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    return s3

def create_bucket(bucket_name):

    return s3_client().create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint':'eu-central-1'})

def create_bucket_policy():
    bucket_policy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AddPerm",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": ["s3:*"],
                "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::some-backet-name/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    policy_string = json.dumps(bucket_policy)
    
    return s3_client.put_bucket_policy(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Policy=policy_string
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket_name = 'some-backet-name'
    #create_bucket(bucket_name)
    create_bucket_policy()
```

Gone through the https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-bucket-policies.html

Below is the erro

"errorMessage": "'function' object has no attribute 'put_bucket_policy'",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have no `s3_client` variable. In fact you have a function named `s3_client`. I fixed this below to call `s3_client()` instead.

Also keep an eye on aligning for Python.

```py
import json
import boto3


def s3_client():

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    return s3

def create_bucket(bucket_name):

    return s3_client().create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint':'eu-central-1'})

def create_bucket_policy():
    bucket_policy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AddPerm",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": ["s3:*"],
                "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::some-backet-name/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    policy_string = json.dumps(bucket_policy)
    
    return s3_client().put_bucket_policy(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Policy=policy_string
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket_name = 'some-backet-name'
    #create_bucket(bucket_name)
    print (create_bucket_policy())
```

As an improvement you could initialise the `s3_client` as a **global variable**. By doing this it will be initialised once, and can actually be reused between multiple invocations of a Lambda function that exist on the same host. I have done this for you below.

```
import json
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def create_bucket(bucket_name):

    return s3_client.create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint':'eu-central-1'})

def create_bucket_policy():
    bucket_policy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AddPerm",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": ["s3:*"],
                "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::some-backet-name/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    policy_string = json.dumps(bucket_policy)
    
    return s3_client.put_bucket_policy(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Policy=policy_string
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket_name = 'some-backet-name'
    #create_bucket(bucket_name)
    print (create_bucket_policy())
```